# Debugging yaml pipeline script

Tags: azure, docker, dockerfile, azure-pipelines

I'm trying to debug a pipeline script in Azure to see what the variables are, but I'm not sure of the syntax.

I have looked through the documentation

### What I have tried so far

```yaml
parameters:
  deploymentName: ""
  dependsOn: ""
  env: ""
  dockerfilePath: ""
  buildContext: ""
  repository: ""
  envGroup: ""
  dockerRegistryServiceConnection: ""
  tag: ""
  token: ""
  runTests: ""

jobs:
  - deployment: ${{ parameters.deploymentName }}
    dependsOn: ${{ parameters.dependsOn }}
    pool: "Private Docker"
    environment: "${{ parameters.envGroup }}"
    strategy:
      runOnce:
        deploy:
          steps:
            - checkout: self
            - task: Docker@2
              displayName: "ACR Login"
              inputs:
                command: login
                containerRegistry: "${{ parameters.dockerRegistryServiceConnection }}"
            ##[debug]Debug!!!!!1 $runTests
            ##[debug]Debug!!!!!2 $parameters.runTests
            ##[debug]Debug!!!!!3 ${{parameters.runTests}}
            - script: echo runTests in dockerbuild.yml ${{parameters.runTests}}
            - script: echo runTests in dockerbuild.yml $parameters.runTests
            - script: echo runTests in dockerbuild.yml $runTests
            - task: Docker@2
              displayName: Build
              inputs:
                command: build
                repository: "${{ parameters.repository }}"
                buildContext: "${{ parameters.buildContext }}"
                dockerfile: "${{ parameters.dockerfilePath }}"
                arguments: "--build-arg TOKEN=${{ parameters.token }} --build-arg RUNTESTS=${{ parameters.runTests }}"
                tags: |
                  $(Build.BuildId)
                  latest
```

### Problem

The debug and echo do not print anything in the azure pipeline build:

```
##[debug]Debug!!!!!1 $runTests
            ##[debug]Debug!!!!!2 $parameters.runTests
            ##[debug]Debug!!!!!3 ${{parameters.runTests}}
            - script: echo runTests in dockerbuild.yml ${{parameters.runTests}}
            - script: echo runTests in dockerbuild.yml $parameters.runTests
            - script: echo runTests in dockerbuild.yml $runTests
```

### Question

Is this the correct syntax for printing to the azure bash when running the yaml file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Debugging yaml pipeline script

It seems that you did not define the parameters correctly. We need provide the `name`, `displayName`, `type`, `default`, `values` like following (Not every attribute is required):

```
parameters:
  - name: deploymentName
    type: string
    default: Product
```

Then we could use the `${{ parameters.deploymentName }}` to get the value.

Please check this document [Runtime parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/runtime-parameters?view=azure-devops&tabs=script) for some more details.

My test YAML file:

```
parameters:
  - name: deploymentName
    type: string
    default: Product
  - name: dependsOn
    type: string
    default: Test
  - name: envGroup
    type: string
    default: test
  - name: runTests
    type: number
    default: 123



stages:
- stage: Build
  jobs:
  - job: Build
    displayName: Build
    pool:
     name: MyPrivateAgent
    steps:
    - script: echo This is for Build


- stage: Dev
  jobs:
    - job: Test
      displayName: Test
      pool:
        name: MyPrivateAgent
      steps:
      - script: echo This is for test
    

    - deployment: ${{ parameters.deploymentName }}
      dependsOn: ${{ parameters.dependsOn }}
      pool:
        name: MyPrivateAgent
      environment: "${{ parameters.envGroup }}"
      strategy:
        runOnce:
          deploy:
            steps:
              - checkout: self
              - script: echo runTests in dockerbuild.yml ${{parameters.runTests}}
```

The test result:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
${{ parameters.runTests}}
```